# Error installing the linearmodels package on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, package

I am trying to install the linearmodels package on Jupyter notebook using the following code:

```
pip install linearmodels
```

but I am getting the following error message:

```
      File "<ipython-input-47-dc9347e29b91>", line 1
    pip install linear models
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can you anyone please help me with this?

After installing the linearmodels package I'll be importing a two-stage instrumental variables regression:

```
from linearmodels.iv import IV2SLS
```

Comment: Where are you running that command? From a terminal window?

Comment: @Watty62 Nope, on Jupyter. Should I be running it on Anaconda prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install packages for Jupyter notebooks there are a couple of ways of approaching it. One way is to `pip install` from the terminal.

The other (proper) way is to use Conda install as explained [here](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-packages) - updated link 21-Sep-2019

Answer (score 1):

I just met the same problem as you. I figured it out that all you need to do is add a "!" at the beginning in the anaconda environment.

```
!pip install linearmodels
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to the anaconda prompt and type:

```
install -c conda-forge linearmodels
```

Source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/linearmodels